# Getting blank RecyclerView inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I'm trying to use CardView , inside the CardView i placed  UI widgets 2 TextViews and 2 ImageViews. My RecyclerView is used to display a list of Cardviews

Here's my Java Class model:

```
public class Masar {

public String masarName;
public String masarDesc;
public int imgl;

public Masar(String masarName, String masarDesc) {
    this.masarName = masarName;
    this.masarDesc = masarDesc;
}

public Masar(String masarName, String masarDesc, int imgl) {
    this.masarName = masarName;
    this.masarDesc = masarDesc;
    this.imgl = imgl;
}

public String getMasarName() {
    return masarName;
}

public String getMasarDesc() {
    return masarDesc;
}

public int getImgl() {
    return imgl;
}
}
```

And here's my Adapter class:

```
public class MasarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasarAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Masar> masrList;

public MasarAdapter(Context mContext, List<Masar> masrList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.masrList = masrList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.masar_items, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Masar masar=masrList.get(position);
    holder.masarName.setText(masar.getMasarName());
    holder.masarDesc.setText(masar.getMasarDesc());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView masarName, masarDesc;
    public ImageView masarImg;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        masarName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masarName);
        masarDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masarDesc);
        masarImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    }
}
}
```

I've tried several times to find out why i'm getting blank result .. Could you please help to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning 0 in your getItemCount() method.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

It should be:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return masrList.size();
}
```